# Python messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter

Below is my code, I can't make it start another question if a question is answered.

I have a list of questions that the app asks, but it is pointless to post them all here. I just can't figure out how to keep on asking questions.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from tkinter import ttk


def correct():
    vastus = ('correct')
    messagebox.showinfo(message=vastus)   



def first():
    box = Tk()
    box.title('First question')
    box.geometry("300x300")

    silt = ttk.Label(box, text="Question")
    silt.place(x=5, y=5)

    answer = ttk.Button(box, text="Answer 1", command=correct)
    answer.place(x=10, y=30, width=150,)


    answer = ttk.Button(box, text="Answer 2",command=box.destroy)
    answer.place(x=10, y=60, width=150)


    answer = ttk.Button(box, text="Answer 3", command=box.destroy)
    answer.place(x=10, y=90, width=150)



first()
```

Comment: Can you expand your code extract to actually include a call to `correct` i.e. your message box?

Comment: When correct is answered then it calls the messagebox. But I can't understand your question.

Comment: Nevermind, I missed the `command=correct` part on the first button.

Comment: Can’t you just call the next question from within the correct function?

Comment: I have tried that but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

from what I can tell, you question is very vague.

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo()
```

is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could either just run the next question from within your correct function, or if you abstract your QA dialog a bit more, you could probably make it a lot more flexible. I was a bit bored, so I built something that supports a dynamic number of questions (with only 3 answers currently though):

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class Question:
    def __init__ (self, question, answers, correctIndex=0):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correct = correctIndex

class QuestionApplication (tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.question = ttk.Label(self)
        self.question.pack(side='top')

        self.answers = []
        for i in range(3):
            answer = ttk.Button(self)
            answer.pack(side='top')
            self.answers.append(answer)

    def askQuestion (self, question, callback=None):
        self.callback = callback
        self.question['text'] = question.question

        for i, a in enumerate(question.answers):
            self.answers[i]['text'] = a
            self.answers[i]['command'] = self.correct if i == question.correct else self.wrong

    def correct (self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(message="Correct")
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()

    def wrong (self):
        if self.callback:
            self.callback()

# configure questions
questions = []
questions.append(Question('Question 1?', ('Correct answer 1', 'Wrong answer 2', 'Wrong answer 3')))
questions.append(Question('Question 2?', ('Wrong answer 1', 'Correct answer 2', 'Wrong answer 3'), 1))

# initialize and start application loop
app = QuestionApplication(master=tkinter.Tk())
def askNext ():
    if len(questions) > 0:
        q = questions.pop(0)
        app.askQuestion(q, askNext)
    else:
        app.master.destroy()

askNext()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: @user1794625 Please remember to upvote helpful answers, and accept one if it solved your problem.